# nodejs - unable to require('child_process').exec from win8

Tags: node.js, steroids

I'm trying to install/run steroids on win8. I've hacked an install that seems to work except for 1 problem - it won't open the browser to show a QR code.

I traced the issue to open.js: line 51

```
// exec string is as follows:
//      start "" "chrome" "http://localhost:4567/__appgyver/connect/qrcode.html?qrCodeData=appgyver%3A%2F%2F%3Fips%3D%255B%2522192.168.1.9%2522%252C%2522127.0.0.1%2522%255D%26port%3D4567"
return exec(opener + ' "' + escape(target) + '"', callback);
```

I logged the output string and copy/pasted it in a CMD window. It successfully launched Chrome and loaded the correct URL.

So why isn't node opening the browser?

Comment: Does it give any error ?

Comment: This: `> require('child_process').exec('start chrome http://www.google.com')` works for me. What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: No error, and I'm using node v0.10.23. If I start the node interpreter and enter the above, the browser window will open. But it doesn't work from Steroids, which uses the open module. I can log the target and open the page manually in Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: AppGyver employee here – I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/49) on the subject, we'll look into it! Do tell us if you find out a solution.